# Cassandra - Primary key with column which I want to update

Tags: cassandra, one-to-many, data-modeling

I need to build table in Cassandra to store operation statuses.
My model looks like this:

```
import 1.. * import_statuses
```

table import:

```
id - 1
date - 2016-08-09
```

table import_statuses:

```
id - 232
import_id - 1
status - IMPORT
```

And now I have to search in import and on the status in second table. But I need only last status from second table.

Denormalized data in these two tables:

```
1, 2016-08-09, 232, 1 IMPORT
1, 2016-08-09, 233, 1 SENDING
1, 2016-08-09, 234, 1 SENT
2, 2016-08-11, 235, 2 IMPORT
2, 2016-08-11, 236, 2 SENDING
```

And I need to get only rows third and fifth:

```
1, 2016-08-09, 234, 1 SENT
2, 2016-08-11, 236, 2 SENDING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create the following two tables, and would update both:

```
CREATE TABLE import (
  id int,
  status_id int,
  date date static,
  status text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, status_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (status_id DESC);

CREATE TABLE last_import_status (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  date date, 
  status_id int,
  status text
);
```

The first one contains the denormalized data, but as the date field is static, it is stored only once for every import. The status records are stored in descending order - I understood that this is an increasing number. If status_id is not an ever-increasing number, you could add a timeuuid field, and use that as clustering key (second field in the PRIMARY KEY).

The last_import_status table will contain a record for each import, and the status_id and status fields will always contain the last value.

Comment: Ok, could you write sample select query to retreive all rows that have status xx ?

Comment: Cassandra has the concept of "Model around your queries", which basically says that you need to know all your queries before coming up a good design. [This document](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling) contains the basic design rules, you can also watch the [Data Modeling](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling) course of DataStax. The short answer is that you probably need an additional table which stores the entries by status, but the proper design depends on the other possible query fields.